# Prevent JsonResult from auto-formatting Dates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, datetime, azure, cloud

I'm writing a cloud based program that utilizes UTC for date saving to the server, and convert it back on the round trip. Problem is, my instance in the cloud is autoconverting the JsonResult datetime values according to the localization settings on the browser obtaining the result.

I have gone through tons of steps to make sure the server side code on both levels is returning the proper data, and it is on all instances, and no Javascript code on my page is making the change either (even removed all my Javascript date formatting just in case), I have traced out with Firebug to determine the exact point that it changes, is when my page receives the Json Result from my JsonResult method. Like I said, I have debugged the values before being sent to the page, and they are proper, and on my response, they are modified based upon browser location....

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Value returned:Date(1341792000000) 07/08/2012 17:00

Should be: Date(1341817200000) (07/09/2012 12:00AM)

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about automatic conversion to local time or formatting? And the unwanted behavior occurs when getting the sent date on the server or when sending something back to the client? I would also opt to remove the azure-tag..

Comment: This is a Azure cloud based issue, that is why I tagged it with Azure. The issue occurs upon returning a JsonResult... all values on the server before sending it to the client are accurate... but when the JsonResult returns my objects, they contain a modified datetime based upon browser local differences from the server.

Comment: There are dates that I need formatted for a specific timezone, no matter where the browser which loads the page resides, that is the fundamental issue I need to solve.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781121/convert-json-dates-without-timezone or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569421/net-json-serializer-returns-local-client-time-to-browser ? I still think that this is not related to Azure and just a "normal" JSON/JavaScript issue. Would you mind adding what values you were getting in firebug, what you returned and what you expected?

Comment: Value returned:Date(1341792000000) 07/08/2012 17:00 , should be Date(1341817200000) (07/09/2012 12:00AM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up getting the proper results, with many modifications to my application. I did a lot of stuff to make this happen... First, I implemented timezone.JS to get a listing of timezones that will be used within the application, and used jstz to get current timezone of browser loading the page. Next, I have to make (for mvc) an file get method that accesses the timezones to load into timezoneJS.

Next, on save of the timezone, I specified pst as the type, and then convert back to utc on roundtrip to update the interface.

On formatting of my Json date, I run the timezoneJS method and get the timezone name from jstz, and set the new date value like such:

```
var timezone = jstz.determine();
timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = '/Item/GetTz'; // get file method
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6), timezone.name())); // strips out date from json date
dt.setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
```

This allows on the cloud projects to be ran on any server, and displayed in any browser regardless of timezone, and allow the user to view and configure timezone sensitive data natively, and allow for users to see the start/end date of configurable database values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I have tried using this to specify it as 'local', 'unspecified' and 'utc' and all three produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with,

```
date.toLocaleString()
```

Alternatively,
You can create a new `Date` object and use `Date.setUTC`

Comment: Do you want it to be MM/DD/YYYY XX:YY AM/PM format? What is the current format?

Answer (score 0):

As the OP said:

> Problem is, my instance in the cloud is autoconverting the JsonResult datetime values according to the localization settings on the browser obtaining the result.

Recently experienced something similar. Strange behavior coming from `$.ajax` response. Depending on the language setting of the browser, a date received in string format gets converted into whatever is set in the language setting.

For example, in Postman, Web API response is like so:

```
{
  "id": "10057",
  "d_date": "3/30/2017 3:00:00 AM",
  "sum": 253.0
},
```

If the browser is set to english(en/en-us), response is the same as above.

If the browser is set to english-uk(en-gb), response becomes:

```
{
  "id": "10057",
  "d_date": "30/03/2017 03:00:00",
  "sum": 253
}
```

If the browser is set to german(de), response becomes:

```
{
  "id": "10057",
  "d_date": "30.03.2017 03:00:00",
  "sum": 253
}
```

So somehow, the browser or the `$.ajax` library is trying to be smart and formatting the dates automatically.

Probably, the best solution is that the Web API send the date in ISO date time format.
Another solution if you can't change the backend is to add **accept-language: en** in the AJAX header request. Something like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/endpoint/',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(body),
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  headers: {
    'accept-language': 'en'
  }
})
```